# Numpy Indexing with Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 2 arrays [nx1] that store xpixel (sample) and ypixel (line) coordinates, respectively.  I have another array [nxn] storing an image.  What I would like to do is create a third array which stores the pixel values from the image array at the given coordinates.  I have this working with the following, but wonder if a built-in numpy function would be more efficient.

```
#Create an empty array to store the values from the image.
newarr = numpy.zeros(len(xsam))

#Iterate by index and pull the value from the image.  
#xsam and ylin are the line and sample numbers.

for x in range(len(newarr)):
    newarr[x] = image[ylin[x]][xsam[x]]

print newarr
```

A random generator determines the length of xsam and ylin along with the direction of travel through the image.  It is therefore totally different with each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: image = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
In [3]: ylin = np.array([0, 3, 2, 2])
In [4]: xsam = np.array([2, 3, 0, 1])
In [5]: newarr = image[ylin, xsam]
In [6]: newarr
array([ 2, 15,  8,  9])
```

Answer (score 3):

If `image` is a numpy array and `ylin`, `xsam` are one dimensional:

```
newarr = image[ylin, xsam]
```

If `ylin`, `xsam` are two-dimensional with the second dimension being `1` e.g., `ylin.shape == (n, 1)` then convert them to one-dimensional form first:

```
newarr = image[ylin.reshape(-1), xsam.reshape(-1)]
```

Comment: You don't have to unravel `ylin` and `xsam`. If you don't do that, `newarr` will keep the same shape as `ylin` or `xsam`, which is quite useful (of course, the code from the OP returns a 1D `newarr`, but you could just `.squeeze` `newarr` at the end if you want that).